# How a class method, can pass the data stored to other method in the same class

Tags: java

I took this class from a book I'm studying. But the book is not precisely explaining how the return value of the `translate` method then is used in the `translateWord` method below, and so on. The only thing the book said is:

> The translate method passes each word to the private support method translateWord.

Yeah, but I want to know how that happen. I ask because I already end the chapter of JAVA CLASSES and I don't understand the process yet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatinTranslator {

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    //Translates a sentence of words into Pig Latin.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    public static String translate(String sentence)
    {
        String result = "";

        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(sentence);

        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            result += translateWord(scan.next());
            result += " ";
        }

        return result;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Translates one word into Pig Latin. If the word begins with a vowel,
    //the suffix 'yay' is appended to the word. Otherwise, the first letter
    //or two are moved to the end of the word, and 'ay' is appended.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static String translateWord(String word)
    {
        String result = "";

        if(beginsWithVowel(word))
            result = word + "yay";
        else
            if(beginsWithBlend(word))
                result = word.substring(2) + word.substring(0,2) + "ay";
            else
                result = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0) + "ay";

        return result;

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Determines if the specified word begins with a vowel.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static boolean beginsWithVowel(String word)
    {
        String vowels = "aeiou";

        char letter = word.charAt(0);

        return(vowels.indexOf(letter) != -1);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Determines if the specified word begins with a particular two-character
    //consonant blend.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static boolean beginsWithBlend(String word)
    {
        return( word.startsWith("bl") || word.startsWith("sc") ||
                word.startsWith("br") || word.startsWith("sh") ||
                word.startsWith("ch") || word.startsWith("sk") ||
                word.startsWith("cl") || word.startsWith("sl") ||
                word.startsWith("cr") || word.startsWith("sn") ||
                word.startsWith("dr") || word.startsWith("sm") ||
                word.startsWith("dw") || word.startsWith("sp") ||
                word.startsWith("fl") || word.startsWith("sq") ||
                word.startsWith("fr") || word.startsWith("st") ||
                word.startsWith("gl") || word.startsWith("sw") ||
                word.startsWith("gr") || word.startsWith("th") ||
                word.startsWith("kl") || word.startsWith("tr") ||
                word.startsWith("ph") || word.startsWith("tw") ||
                word.startsWith("pl") || word.startsWith("wh") ||
                word.startsWith("pr") || word.startsWith("wr"));

    }







}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: parameters: after a call like `translateWord("foobar")`, **in** the method `translateWord`, `word` has the value "foobar". Some reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 1):

As the [`Javadoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--)  shows, the `next()` method yields back a string. The `translateWord(String word)` accepts a string as a parameter, so anything which by the end of the day resolves to a `String` can be passed on to this method.

Thus, this line: `translateWord(scan.next());` is essentially short hand for the following code:

```
String scannerInput = scan.next();
translateWord(scannerInput);
```

Given a string, `This is a test`, the scanner will return `This`, `is`, `a`, `test`. So those strings would be then fed to your `translateWord` method.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of 'translate' is never used in 'translateWorld'.
How it works :

- in translate you take each work from a sentence
- when the word is isolate, it goes to translateWord
- translateWord make the transformation and give the transformated word to translate
- each translated words are concatenated in a new sentence

The return value of translate will be used in another method or another class.